# How to avoid audio sample 16bit clipping after equalization?

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, pcm

I have samples which come from ffmpeg, very often it is 16 bit samples (short type), i have used iir band pass filter with dbGain as described  [here](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt), after filtering i sometimes got a short type overflow and result of it is some noise when calculated sample value go out from 32767/-32767, Is any way to escape audio pcm sample clipping. May be exists any approaches?

I have googled but not found any worked example?

**UPDATE**

When i cast transfer function calculation result to integer and check overflow then noise still occurs::

```
int result = A1 * ((int) Rx) + A2 * ((int) Rxx) + A3 * ((int) Rxxx)
                    - B1 * ((int) Ryy) - B2 * ((int) Ryyy);
if (result > 32767)
    result = 32767;
if (result < -32700)
    result = -32700;
y = (short) result;
```

Comment: If your filter has positive gain, saturation is a risk you're going to take.  Can you explain your specific question better?

Comment: What do you want to know specifically?

Comment: Well, if you're applying gain, why wouldn't you expect it to overflow/saturate sometimes?

Comment: How can i expect overflow/saturate ?

Comment: your filter implementation should take care of underflow/overflow, you can "clip, "floor" "saturate" the final result. you should use higher precision (32/64 bit) for "intermediate result".

Comment: @testCoder, imagine you had a signal that was all +32767.  If you apply any positive gain to that signal it will have to overflow.  Only if your filter has 0 or negative gain can you be safe from overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16-bit PCM samples will have to be in range [-32768..+32767]. If you apply math (biquad filter in your case) onto input signal, the output is not guaranteed to stay within the range, which is the inevitable outcome here in case you are applying positive gain.

Since hitting range boundaries is a natural side effect with this kind of processing, you are supposed to take care of it using one of the approaches (the list is not supposed to be full):

- make sure your input signal is quiet enough and/or shift values right by a few bits to provide headroom for big values on the output
- use higher bitness for output signal, such as 24-bit PCM
- use floating point PCM for output signal to precision loss on going outside of PCM sample range